# Selenium returns $###.## number format instead of actual value

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Creating a chrome driver instance
Loading it with amazon url
Searching with one plus 9 pro option
Selecting the first result and adding it to cart.
When I use getAttribute("innertext") to retrieve price from the cart.
Selenium returns $###.## instead of actual price.
Can any one help me to get actual price instead of $###.##
Adding sample code.

public class AmazonOnePlus {
ChromeDriver driver;

```
void initializeChrome() {
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(30));
}
    
void openAmazonAndSearch() {
    driver.get("https://www.amazon.in/");
    driver.findElement(By.id("twotabsearchtextbox")).sendKeys("One Plus 9 pro", Keys.ENTER);
}


public void clickImg() {
  driver.navigate().refresh();
  String firstImg = "//div[@class='sg-col-inner']//span/ancestor::div[@class='a-section']/div//img";
  
    
  // open the link in new tab, Keys.Chord string passed to sendKeys
  driver.findElements(By.xpath(firstImg)).get(0).click();
  
   // hold all window handles in array list
   ArrayList<String> newTb = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
   
   // switch to new tab
   driver.switchTo().window(newTb.get(1));
   
}

void getSubTotal(AmazonOnePlus a) {
    driver.findElement(By.id("add-to-cart-button")).click();
    String subtotal = driver.findElement(By.id("attach-accessory-cart-subtotal")).getAttribute("innerText");
    System.out.println("subsss  "+subtotal);
    driver.quit();
    
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  AmazonOnePlus am = new AmazonOnePlus();
  am.initializeChrome();
  am.openAmazonAndSearch();
  am.clickImg();
  am.getSubTotal(am);
}
```

}

Comment: Do you just need to get the price, without the units e.g. no "$"?

Comment: yess @scunliffe